# Forms vs Tables for editable company profile

Tags: meteor

I am starting to build an app, using Meteor, that includes user-populated company profiles (including both financial data and text).  I will be looking into a datafeed for public company information but much of the information for private companies will be user-populated.

I know I will need to create a form for the user to fill in so that the company information will be captured by the database.  However, can I make this same form available to the user to both display the data and to allow them to edit the data in the future?  Or do I need to build a separate view using tables for this purpose? My preference is the former, just one screen to create and edit as needed.

Any examples of similar instances would be very appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is less of a meteor specific question, rather a general web technology question. Meteor can provide the data in the template of course, and it can offer events to process data and insert/update this to a database. This is the same as any underlying architecture. The question is really how to approach the problem with HTML & JavaScript.

A couple of potential methods:

1. Write your HTML to display the content in its non-editable form. Then provide an edit button to switch mode. When clicking this button switch on 'contenteditable' for the elements you wish to be edited: http://html5doctor.com/the-contenteditable-attribute/

Also reveal a save button, then process the event through meteor. Use selectors to extract the fields by referencing either designated class names, data attributes or name attributes. It would also be a good idea to alter the appearance of editable elements with a background or outline. The disadvantage here is that it's slightly non-standard and you may have the need for more complex data-types like dropdowns or checkboxes etc.

2. Create view with a standard form HTML. Style it in a way that shapes the information primarily for display rather than editing, eg. hide form field borders. Provide an edit button that when clicked alters the CSS and reveals form field borders, also reveal/replace elements which need more complex controls like dropdowns, perhaps turn on field labels too and of course a save button. The disadvantage is slightly more complex CSS and JavaScript.

Comment: Ian, thanks very much for your time. I think #2 sounds preferable, as I will likely have drop-downs, check boxes, etc. I think the form here is the solution I had expected, you answered my question with the points on editing the CSS. Not a rush at all, as I won't get to work on this for a few days, but would appreciate any code example you could offer. Thanks again.

Comment: Ok, nps... I'll try to find some time to add a bit of code.